# Generics and Overload Polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have a generic class `TemplateOption<T>` which has a field `callback` which needs to be set to an `Action<T>`. `T` must derive from a type called `BaseObject`.

I have overloaded a function `HandleOption` to accept different objects inheriting from `BaseObject`

```
private void HandleOption(BaseObject obj){ ... }
private void HandleOption(Location loc){ ... }
private void HandleOption(Connection conn) { ... }
...
```

Now I want to have a function `AddHandler` that will assign the right overload of `HandleOption` to a `TemplateOption<T>` object's `callback` field. I tried this,

```
private void AddHandler<T>(TemplateOption<T> opt) where T : BaseObject
{
    opt.callback = HandleOption;
}
```

but the problem is `opt` is treated as a `TemplateOption<BaseObject>`, so only the first overload, `HandleOption(BaseObject)` is ever used. A working solution would be to do

```
private void AddHandler(TemplateOption<BaseObject> opt) { opt.callback = HandleOption; }
private void AddHandler(TemplateOption<Location> opt)   { opt.callback = HandleOption; }
private void AddHandler(TemplateOption<Connection> opt) { opt.callback = HandleOption; }
...
```

but this seems extremely inelegant, having many function overloads where the function body is identical. Is there a better way to do this? Is my approach wrong to begin with?

Comment: I don't know why, but I suspect you have an XY problem....

Comment: What if I write my own subclass of `BaseObject` called `Foo`, and pass a `TemplateOption<Foo>` to `AddHandler`? You don't have an overload of `HandleOption` that accepts a `Foo`, so what do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: @Sweeper Well in that case it should just use `HandleOption(BaseObject)`. What I'd want it to do is use the overload for the derived type if it is available.

Comment: One dirty trick is `opt.Callback = x => HandleOption((dynamic)x);`, delaying the binding to runtime. But if you do this, you can't pass null, or anything else that would make the overload resolution ambiguous, into `callback`. I agree with Mitch that this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I looked up the term XY problem since I hadn't heard it before; I think you guys do have a point in that I'm probably focusing on a specific issue too narrowly. Sweeper's trick does work as a workaround for now though, and if I run into more problems I'll look into more broad refactoring or restructuring. Thanks for your input, and apologies that I didn't make a more relevant or useful post.